# How do extra party members affect fullness when ordering food?

Tags: neo-the-world-ends-with-you

When buying food in *NEO: TWEWY*, every character needs to order something to eat which can quickly fill your fullness bar. Early in the game a new person joins your party, which gives you another mouth to feed when ordering food.

How does having an extra party member affect your fullness bar? Will each food item still fill the same amount?

[image: Fullness bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Each party member adds 1,000 calories to the fullness bar.**

A team with 3 party members will be full after 3,000 calories, 4 after 4,000 calories, and so on. To figure this out, I ate food before and after gaining a party member, then calculated how many calories it took to reach 100% fullness. So with a party of 4, if a burger with 600 calories fills 15%, then:

```
(600 cal/15%)/4 = (40 cal/1%)/4 = (10 cal/1%) = (1000 cal/100%)
```

[As Chronocidal points out](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/389351/how-do-extra-party-members-affect-fullness-when-ordering-food/389779?noredirect=1#comment548288_389779), there is an exception to this. During Week 2 Day 3, you get an option to split the party. If you agree to split the party, you will retain the full set of calories, even though only half the party is present.

Comment: Interestingly, on Week 2 Day 3 there is a point where you can split the party.  When this happens, you retain the full set of calories, even though only half the party is present — letting you eat twice as much food before you get full.

Comment: @Chronocidal How does this work when revisiting W2D3 with chapter select after gaining more party members?

Comment: Replaying the day, the team doesn't split; even if you select the option to do so, you still have a full squad.  So, you can use it to fast-gain stats on the new character unlocked that day, but not long-term.